# My raster does not line up with rest of vector shapefiles, even though both rely on NAD 83

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I started creating a map in ArcMap by adding vector shapefiles. All of my vectors have data sources as:

```
Data Type:  Shapefile Feature Class 
Geometry Type:  Line

Projected Coordinate System:    NAD_1983_StatePlane_North_Carolina_FIPS_3200
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting:  609601.22000000
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian:   -79.00000000
Standard_Parallel_1:    34.33333333
Standard_Parallel_2:    36.16666667
Latitude_Of_Origin: 33.75000000
Linear Unit:    Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

When I bring in a raster image downloaded from a North Carolina imagery earth-explorer database, the raster image looks a few hundred miles off from where it should be. The data source of the raster images is:

```
Spatial Reference: NAD_1983_2011_StatePlane_North_Carolina_FIPS_3200_Ft_US
Linear Unit: Foot_US (0.304801)
Angular Unit: Degree (0.01745329519943295)
Datum: D_NAD_1983_2011
```

When I add the raster, I get the **Geographic Coordinate Systems Warning**, saying that the data source of the raster ("GC_NAD_1983_2011") is different from the one used in the data frame. When I go in the Transformations options in the same dialogue box, and try to "Convert from GCS_NAD_1983_2011" to just "GCS_North_American_1983", there is no method available under the **Using:** dropdown, meaning I can't transform. What can I do to rectify this? How can I change the actual datum of the raster?

Comment: For future reference, [GIS.SE] is generally a faster resource for getting application-specific questions like this answered more quickly. StackOverflow is more for _programming_ questions (like if you want to write a python script to line up your data!)

Answer (score 1):

You can have two different *[projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection)* that share the same *[datum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_datum)*. In this case, ArcMap can't really use a datum transformation because, well, there's nothing to transform -- they're both already NAD83.

Add the raster data into a new, empty map and use the ArcGIS [Project tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000007m000000) (found in the Data Management / Projections and Transformations toolbox). You can put it into the exact same projection as your original data (NAD83 North Carolina State Plane, meters) and everything should line up correctly.

(Note: Don't use [Define Projection](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2013/08/23/when-to-use-the-define-projection-tool-and-the-project-tool-2/) unless your source data doesn't have ANY projection. It will overwrite a projection, not transform. [See here](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2013/08/23/when-to-use-the-define-projection-tool-and-the-project-tool-2/) for an Esri blog post about the difference.)